# How to change Package Code using InstallShield LE 2015

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

Based on the information here http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/isxhelp22/helplibrary/UpgradeConsiderations.htm

in particular "Therefore, you should change the package code for each build."

How to change the Package Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have LE installed but in other versions of InstallSheld that's the default behavior unless you disable it.  The only time I would intentionally disable it is some build reproducibility exercise.  LE probably just doesn't expose it as an option.

Build 2 MSI and look at them using ORCA (Windows Installer Database Editor) and look at the summary information stream of each to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Maybe I am doing something wrong but.

Comment: I have added Upgrade path to project and build new msi. When trying to install it for example having 1.0.11.0 version trying to install 1.0.12.0 version. getting error that product already installed and what I have to uninstall it. but I want just upgrade.

Comment: You have to change the ProductCode when doing a Major Upgrade.

Comment: What is difference between Small Update and Major Upgrade? I am probably confused on that part